# How to get invocationcount and threadpool functionality in junit

Tags: junit

Like the title suggests is there a way to get the invocationCount and threadpool functionality of testng on junit ?
If not can someone suggest a way to get around this ?
Google-ing didn't work and the docs also didn't help, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking at profiling your application? Not sure what those 2 terms are in context of junit

Comment: Threadpoolsize -The size of the thread pool for this method. The method will be invoked from multiple threads as specified by invocationCount.
InvocationCount- The number of times this method should be invoked.
Source: http://testng.org/javadoc/org/testng/annotations/Test.html

Answer (score 0):

There is support in junit for what you need. You can collect those statistics in class level or field level variables declared in the class under test. A very crude implementation would look like this:

```
static AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
static Set<String> threadIds = Collections.newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>());

public void foo() {
     counter.incrementAndGet();
     threadIds.add(Thread.currentThread().getId());
     //do something useful
}
```

Using this approach you end up modifying the code thats under test. Of cource, there are other possible solutions (like using proxies) to avoid this.

Comment: Sorry  I am still relatively new to Java,  can you please explain what you did there ?

Comment: Er...not sure how to simplify this further - you will need to learn a little bit of the language to understand this code